# Entity Framework composite primary key with Object type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, composite-primary-key

I am using Entity framework code first, I want to generate DB from my code like below:
I have 2 entity class, just short for example:

```
Product {
public int id;
public int name;
}

Month{
public int year;
public int month;
}
```

Now I want to make a class 'Report'

```
Report{
public Product product;
public Month month;
public decimal Price;
}
```

I tried to add a composite primary key in my DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasKey(t => new { t.Product.ID, t.Month.ID });
}
```

but the EF tell that 'Report' must have Primary Key from **primitive type** (such as int, char...)
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the composite key to your Report class. You will also need a identifier on your Month class. The syntax below may not be 100%.

```
public class Report
{
   [Key(Order=0)]
   public int ProductId { get; set; }

   [Key(Order=1)]
   public int MonthId { get; set; }

   public Product product { get; set; }

   public Month month { get; set; }

   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```